# phpmyadmin me solicita password XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Hola que tal he instalado XAMPP en mi linux y el servicio de MYSQL esta encendido pero al tratar de usar phpmyadmin este me tira varios errores, adjunto imagen de evidencia. Se que me solicita password pero es la primera vez que instalo XAMPP desconozco que esta pasando.

PD cambie de puerto mysql de 3306 a 3307 y en el archivo config.inc.php configure de 'localhost' a '127.0.0.1' recomendaciones que vi en internet porque el servicio de MYSql no encendia hasta después de hacer esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se han eliminado los errores de la foto ahora me aparece la leyenda "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Conexión rehusada"

Comment: todo era culpa del puerto, muchas garcias!\

Answer (score 2):

Al revisar el post puedo indicarte que revises el archivo "config.inc.php" y verifiques en algún apartado que diga :

```
-'user': root

-'password': "La contraseña que debería ser."
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']= 'root'

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']= ' ' <<<---- Así debería aparecer si no pusiste contraseña a la hora de instalar, si posee una contraseña diferente deberia de aparecer en ese apartado.
```

Mas si no te sirve de mucho mi ayuda, te dejo el link:

[Solucion 1](http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/webapps/lecciones/phpmyadmin-1-soluciones.html)

Comment: Desde el celular es difícil leer las líneas que marcas en tu imagen, por favor considera agregarlas como texto creo que ayudaria mucho a tu respuesta

Comment: Ningún problema, agregado a la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

A menos de que hayas definido una contraseña PHPMyAdmin no la pide, en caso de que te la pida y hayas instalado por primera vez solo da en entrar sin poner nada, por default la contraseña de PHPMyAdmin de XAMPP es "" y por lo que veo estas intentando poner "NO" como contraseña.

Comment: El NO que aparece es parte del mensaje de error, no es por qué lo haya puesto el usuario

Comment: Ciertamente, ya hice pruebas, gracias por corregirme.